# Extract a column value and assign it to another column as an array in Spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, scala-collections

I have a Spark Dataframe with the below columns.

```
C1 | C2 | C3| C4
1  | 2  | 3 | S1
2  | 3  | 3 | S2
4  | 5  | 3 | S2
```

I want to generate another column C5 by taking distinct values from column C4
like                                                                            C5

```
[S1,S2]
[S1,S2]
[S1,S2]
```

Can somebody help me how to achieve this in Spark data frame using Scala?

Comment: Can you explain the relationship with C4 how **S2** generated in C5. What if more than 2 distinct values present in C4 ?

Comment: This post has been discussed in [Assigning columns to another columns in a Spark Dataframe using Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55075286/10465355).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to collect the distinct items from column 4 and put them in a List firstly, and then use `withColumn` to create a new column `C5` by creating a `udf` that always return a constant list:

```
val uniqueVal = df.select("C4").distinct().map(x => x.getAs[String](0)).collect.toList    
def myfun: String => List[String] = _ => uniqueVal 
def myfun_udf = udf(myfun)

df.withColumn("C5", myfun_udf(col("C4"))).show

+---+---+---+---+--------+
| C1| C2| C3| C4|      C5|
+---+---+---+---+--------+
|  1|  2|  3| S1|[S2, S1]|
|  2|  3|  3| S2|[S2, S1]|
|  4|  5|  3| S2|[S2, S1]|
+---+---+---+---+--------+
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this using pyspark?