# Assigning columns to another columns in a Spark Dataframe using Scala

Tags: apache-spark

I was looking at this excellent question so as to improve my Scala skills and the answer: [Extract a column value and assign it to another column as an array in spark dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41294414/extract-a-column-value-and-assign-it-to-another-column-as-an-array-in-spark-data)

I created my modified code as follows which works, but am left with a few questions:

```
import spark.implicits._   
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
    ("r1", 1, 1),
    ("r2", 6, 4),
    ("r3", 4, 1),
    ("r4", 1, 2)
  )).toDF("ID", "a", "b")

val uniqueVal = df.select("b").distinct().map(x => x.getAs[Int](0)).collect.toList    
def myfun: Int => List[Int] = _ => uniqueVal 
def myfun_udf = udf(myfun)

df.withColumn("X", myfun_udf( col("b") )).show

+---+---+---+---------+
| ID|  a|  b|        X|
+---+---+---+---------+
| r1|  1|  1|[1, 4, 2]|
| r2|  6|  4|[1, 4, 2]|
| r3|  4|  1|[1, 4, 2]|
| r4|  1|  2|[1, 4, 2]|
+---+---+---+---------+
```

It works, but:

- I note b column is put in twice.
- I can also put in column a on the second statement and I get the same result. E.g. and what point is that then?

> df.withColumn("X", myfun_udf( col("a") )).show

- If I put in col ID then it gets null.
- So, I am wondering why the second col is input?
- And how this could be made to work generically for all columns?

So, this was code that I looked at elsewhere, but I am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've shown doesn't make much sense:

- It is not scalable - in the worst case scenario size of each row is proportional to the size
- As you've already figure out it doesn't need argument at all.
- It doesn't need (and what's important it didn't need) `udf` at the time it was written (on 2016-12-23 Spark 1.6 and 2.0 where already released)
- If you still wanted to use `udf` nullary variant would suffice

Overall it is just another convoluted and misleading answer that served OP at the point. I'd ignore (or [vote accordingly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)) and move on.

So how could this be done:

- If you have a local list and you really want to use `udf`. For single sequence use `udf` with `nullary` function:

  ```scala
  val uniqueBVal: Seq[Int] = ???
  val addUniqueBValCol = udf(() => uniqueBVal)

  df.withColumn("X", addUniqueBValCol())
  ```

  Generalize to:

  ```scala
  import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag

  def addLiteral[T : TypeTag](xs: Seq[T]) = udf(() => xs)

  val x = addLiteral[Int](uniqueBVal)
  df.withColumn("X", x())
  ```
- Better don't use `udf`:

  ```scala
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

  df.withColumn("x", array(uniquBVal map lit: _*))
  ```
- As of

  > And how this could be made to work generically for all columns?

  as mentioned at the beginning the whole concept is hard to defend. Either window functions (completely not scalable)

  ```scala
  import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

  val w = Window.rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)
  df.select($"*" +: df.columns.map(c => collect_set(c).over(w).alias(s"${c}_unique")): _*)
  ```

  or cross join with aggregate (most of the time not scalable)

  ```scala
  val uniqueValues = df.select(
    df.columns map (c => collect_set(col(c)).alias(s"${c}_unique")):_*
  )
  df.crossJoin(uniqueValues)
  ```

  In general though - you'll have to rethink your approach, if this comes anywhere actual applications, unless you know for sure, that cardinalities of columns are small and  have strict upper bounds.

Take away message is - don't trust random code that random people post in Internet. This one included.